# Unable post using express.js (mean)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express

This is my mongoDb connection

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
// Connection URL  
var db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/employeeDetails';  
    // Use connect method to connect to the Server  
 mongoose.connect(db, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Employee_Schema = new Schema({
    EmployeeName: String,
    Designation: String,
    Project: String,
    Skills:String
});

var Employee = mongoose.model('employees', Employee_Schema);

 module.exports=Employee;
```

This is my api code (express.js)

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();
var Employee=require('../database/dataFile');

router.get('/',function(req,resp,next){
    Employee.find({},function(err,docs){
        resp.send(docs);
    })
});

router.post('/create',function(req, resp, next){

    var employee_collection =Employee.collection(Employee);
    employee_collection.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(doc);
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

 module.exports=router;
```

This is my $http.post

```
create(employee: Employee) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:4500/api/create', employee).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

I always get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

FYI: $http.get works fine. It fetches data from MongoDb. The following hit the get method in api

```
getEmployeeList() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4500/api');
}
```

Please note I am taking example from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1185294/Build-Modern-App-with-MEAN-Stack-Part)
This tutorial does not have `Post` functionality and I am trying to implement.

Comment: have you used Http or HttpClient? in your post the request must contain HttpParams type, you have given employee type in your post request. Also I can see that your context path of api is given as "/create".

Comment: I didn't get your point. please be more elaborative

Comment: try this router.post('/api/create'.... and if you are using HttpClient you dont need to map it to json() it is by default a json()

Answer (score 1):

There Is A problem with the query, If you want to fetch the collection use:

```
mongoose.getCollection(<collection name>), But here you are calling the collection function on a model object, not the mongoose one.
```

Instead, I Would recommend using .create directly:

```
Employee.create(req.body, function(err,result){
   if(err){throw Error(err)}
   return res.json(result);
})
```

Comment: Your Welcome. :)